# how to decode an hexacidemal values to decimal ones with springboot?

Tags: spring-boot, hex, decimal, decode

i don't know how to decode  hexacidemal values to decimal ones  with springboot
Is There a default fonctions That can help me or should i develop functions by myself
thank You

Answer (score 0):

You just need JAVA APIs,

### From Hexadecimal to Decimal

```
String hexNumber = ...
int decimal = Integer.parseInt(hexNumber, 16);
System.out.println("Hex value is " + decimal);
```

### From Decimal to Hex

If you have the value that you want to convert in an int variable, then you can simply call:

```
int i = ...
String hex = Integer.toHexString(i);
System.out.println("Hex value is " + hex);
```

If you have the decimal number in a String, then you first call `Integer.parseInt()` but this time you don't need any second parameter— decimal is the default:

```
String string = ...
int no = Integer.parseInt(string);
String hex = Integer.toHexString(no);
System.out.println("Hex value is " + hex);
```

Check out the full paper [here](https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/conversion/decimal_hexadecimal.shtml).

Comment: The answer uses variables.

Comment: Thanks @Philippe Simo